# Ubuntu 14.04 can't connect to WI-FI

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.6 alongside Windows on my Lenovo Yoga PC.

When I try to connect to my home Wi-Fi network it can't find any connection. There is no connections list at all.

I have checked the soft/hard block and it's in unblock mode.

How can I fix it without a connection?

Comment: Why use a version of Ubuntu which is end-of-life? What happens when you boot from a LiveUSB with a supported LTS version,  such as 16.04 http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/

Comment: My professor recommended it.. what will it take for me to upgrade it to 16?

Comment: Your prof may not understand there's no "Standard" (i.e., open) support for 14.04 anymore https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life/  https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/04/ubuntu-14-04-end-of-life   outside of large corporations who pay Canonical for support. However, you don't need to install the OS, but can run it from the LiveUSB used to install it. Is your PC 32-bit or 64-bit? How much RAM does it have? When you run `sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'` what's the result? Please click [edit] and put the answers in your question.

Comment: You should upgrade to the latest version, whatever your prof says. It's not only a matter of comfort, but also one of security. Listen to what @K7AAY wrote instead.

Comment: However, you don't need to install the OS, but you can test it by booting from the LiveUSB used to install it. 1) Is your PC 32-bit or 64-bit? 2) How much RAM does it have? 3) What is the model of that Lenovo PC? It's on the same sticker as the serial number; other 'model numbers' elsewhere are more like marketing names and don't help us with the system details. 4) When you run _sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'_ what's the result? Please copy the text of the result, click [edit]  and paste the result of #4 in your question along with the answers to #1, #2, and #3..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu v. 18.04 LTS (unless it's a 32-bit system, in which case use 16.04 LTS), which is stable and guaranteed to be supported for 10 years (until 2018). What it takes is downloading the ISO image [from Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/), putting it on a USB flash drive [with Rufus](https://linuxhint.com/rufus_bootable_usb_install_ubuntu_18-04_lts/) (you'll need at least 8 GB, formatted FAT32, not exFAT), and testing it by booting from the USB stick.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS should have drivers fro the Lenovo Yoga, whereas older versions might not. If all works while running from the USB drive, ncluding internet access, select Installation, and install as much as you'd like, either as the only OS or dual boot. For my use, I include the usual apps (e.g. Firefox and Thunderbird) as well as third-party tools... but go with the course requirements. Full installation usually takes less than a half hour.

See [Infofuge](https://www.infofuge.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-920-dual-boot/) for details on dual booting.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but I want to use Ubunto 14..

Comment: Does 14.04, released in 2014, have drivers for your PC? If the Yoga is more recent, you'll have to look for *specific drivers* to install.